# Has there been a funeral yet? / Has the funeral taken place yet?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Would both of my suggestions be perfectly natural or how would you typically ask the question?

*He died five days ago.*

***Has there been a funeral yet?** / **Has the funeral taken place yet?***

Comment: Both are completely correct.  What raises doubt for you in this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Here are some options, and there are probably more:

Has there been a funeral [yet/already]?
Has the funeral taken place [yet/already]?
Have they had a funeral [yet/already]?
Did they have a funeral [yet/already]?
Has the funeral already happened?